# Using Angular2 and SailsJS (without exposing node_modules)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, sails.js

I've found some articles and guides about how to integrate Angular2 into your SailsJS app, but all of them require to expose your `node_modules` directory to the public.

Additionally, most of these guides require running `tsc` before lifting Sails. Since TypeScript grunt tasks are easily defined there should be a better way which doesn't require anything to be run before lifting the app.

It just doesn't feel right to make your `node_modules` directory public and I'm trying to find a different way.

**First edit**: my first approach:

1. Copying the angular directories from `node_modules` to `assets/vendor` via the `grunt copy` task
2. Defining a `grunt-ts` task (https://gist.github.com/nehalist/6eea5c076d187d785d6c6486f5174c32)
3. Adding the following references to the `layout.ejs`
4. Creating the `systemjs.config.js` in `assets/js` (https://gist.github.com/nehalist/6eea5c076d187d785d6c6486f5174c32#file-gistfile2-txt)

`grunt ts` should now compile the TypeScript into `.tmp/js` - but sadly I got a lot of missing type errors;

```
Running "ts:assets" (ts) task
Compiling...
Fast compile will not work when --out is specified. Ignoring fast compilation
Using tsc v2.0.10
assets/vendor/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/resource_loader/resource_loader_impl.d.ts(10,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts(369,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts(415,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts(416,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
```

**Second edit**: Fixed compile errors by setting the `grunt-ts` target to es6. Now everything compiles, but sadly still doesn't work - seems like my app is never initialized.

Everything is compiled, but it seems like systemjs doesn't start the app? Or something like that, I'm not sure yet.